# Entity Framework Creating a model using views instead of tables

Tags: view, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6 and need to modify my code to use views instead of tables. I've have found a few questions/answers posted on how to modify the .edmx so that the views will act as tables that have an association with them. Most of the responses are quite old and I was wondering if there was an easier way available now that can be used? For example say you are using the 2 tables from the Northwind database (Categories and Products). How would modify the .edmx if now the are wrapped in a view (vCategories and vProducts). hopefully, there is an easier way than making all these edits.

Comment: First, don't use EDMX for views, because they can only read the entire view. Contrary to reading from tables, projections (i.e. `Select(x => new { })` will still read all view columns and the projection is dealt with client-side. Second, EDMX views can't be updated. If you want that, you have to use code-first and the database views must be updatable. Third, *easier way* -- you don't really make clear what that means. Easier than what? Please try to clarify in a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not looking to do any updating with the views. When say read entire view do you mean that I can't put a where clause so that I can limit the amount of data I get back?

Comment: Yes you can use `Where`, but if you do `Select(x => x.ID)` EF, using EDMX, will read all columns of the view in the SQL `SELECT` clause. With a table, EF will generate a `SELECT` clause reading only `ID`. So using views can be a serious performance killer. In code-first, EF doesn't see the difference between a view and a table.

Comment: So if there are only a few columns in the view this really shouldn't be too much of an issue? Also, you are saying that if I use Code-First I would not have any of these issues? So, all of my existing code would not have to be changed if I switch to code first?

Comment: With code-first it's much easier to map entities to views and set relationships & navigation properties between them. But switching from db-first to code-first itself can be a daunting task. I hope you've got your regression testing in order.

Comment: Do you know of an example I can use to test it out. I'm not finding any. That would be very helpful. My sample project is very small.